# Request a single entity by $filter

Tags: odata

I'm calling a bound function. It works fine when I request the entity by its key:

```
/MyEntity(1)/MyFunction
```

However, I have to request the entity by MyField, which is unique but it isn't the key:

```
/MyEntity?$filter=MyField eq 1
```

What is the syntax for calling a function in this case? Just adding "/MyFunction" to the end doesn't work:

```
/MyEntity?$filter=MyField eq 1/MyFunction
```

This is not surprising, since $filter actually returns not an entity, but a collection of one single entity. I guess, basically what I need is to get the first entity from the payload.

I've looked through [the documentation](http://www.odata.org/documentation/), but couldn't find the answer, it seems I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. You could do this in two steps: $select the ID when $filter-ing and then in a second request use the gotten ID to execute the function.

Comment: @GWigWam well, it's the obvious way. The question is - is it possible to request an entity by any unique property aside from the key.

Comment: Would `/MyEntity/MyFunction(MyField=1)` suffice? That is possible, you just add an argument to your action signature. (Assuming you control the OData service)

Comment: @GWigWam, yes, it is another workaround.

Comment: If you want I could post an answer showing how to do that with ASP.Net-WebAPI OData on the server side. Would that be helpful to you? Or have you figured it out yourself.

Comment: @GWigWam it wouldn't, I know how to add a parameter to a function. My question regards the OData syntax only.